# How to call java method from javascript method that located within another jsni method

Tags: gwt, jsni

```
 public class A{
    private void javaMethod(int a,int b){}

    private native void init()/*-{
            function OnMouseMove(e) {
             //blow calling doesn't work
              this.@p::javaMethod(Ljava/...teger;Ljava.../Integer;)(intVal,intVal);
            }
    }-*/;
  }
```

---

As described above,how to make that invoking work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answered on the Google Group: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/google-web-toolkit/qE2-L4u_t4s/YqjOu-bUfsAJ

Copied here for reference and convenience:

First, `int` is not `java.lang.Integer`, so your method signature in JSNI is wrong; it should read `javaMethod(II)`.
(I suppose the `@p::` while javaMethod is defined in class A is over-simplification in your question, but is OK in your code)

You'll also probably have a problem with `this`, that might not be what you think it is. A common pattern is to assign the current object (`this`, at the time) to a variable that you'll reference from your closure:

```
var that = this;
…
function OnMouseMove(e) {
   that.@p.A::javaMethod(II)(intVal, intVal);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're doing two things wrong:

- You're not defining the class name after `@p`, (assuming `@p` is actually just a shortened version of the real package's name);
- You're attempting to pass `java.lang.Integer` in place of `int`. You should be saying `(II)` as the types, as described [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/jni/spec/types.html#wp16432).

Your code should look more like this:

```
package com.my.package;

public class ClassA {
    private static void javaMethod(int a, int b) { ... }
    public static native void init() /*-{
       $wnd.javaMethod = function(a, b) {
          return @com.my.package.ClassA::javaMethod(II)(a,b);
       }
       function OnMouseMove(e) {
          $wnd.javaMethod(a,b);
       }
    }-*/;
}
```

Comment: Sorry,I can't understand your code.In my code,"OnMouseMove(e)" locates within a JSNI method,and I want to call java method from this:OnMouseMove(e)

Comment: @AlexLuya added a more precise example. Also, as Thomas Broyer pointed out, you're probably expecting `this` to be something it's not.